# Multiple file uploads - how can i integrate thumbnail function for all uploaded files?

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, file-upload, image-uploading

These are my codes for multiple upload files..

Please can you help me with code in exchange which also have thumbnail integration

```
public function addimage($room_id)
{

    $name_array = array();
    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
    for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];  
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        //$config['encrypt_name'] = uniqid(date(1));
        // $config['max_size']  = '100';
        // $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        // $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
    } // end foreach
    $names= array($name_array);
    print_r($names);


    exit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-initialize the image library with:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$image_config = array(
'source_image'      => $image_data['full_path'],
'new_image'         => $this->thumbs_path,
'maintain_ratio'    => true,
'width'             => 36,
'height'            => 36
);

$this->image_lib->clear();
$this->image_lib->initialize($image_config);  
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this ?

```
public function addimage($room_id)
{

    $this->load->library("image_lib");
    $name_array = array();
    $count = count($_FILES['userfile']['size']);
    foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
    for($s=0; $s<$count; $s++) {
        $_FILES['userfile']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
        $_FILES['userfile']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];  
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        //$config['encrypt_name'] = uniqid(date(1));
        // $config['max_size']  = '100';
        // $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        // $config['max_height']  = '768';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload();
        $data = $this->upload->data();
        $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];

        //thumbnail creation
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $data['file_name'];
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']         = 200;
        $config['height']       = 200;
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();



    } // end foreach
    $names= array($name_array);
    print_r($names);


    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am understanding your question, I would refer you to read about the Image Manipulation Library of codeigniter.

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

There is a thumbnail creation. You can create thumbnail using the returned data after a successful upload.

Comment: Codeigniter user guides now found here http://www.codeigniter.com/docs and img_lib http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: Sorry, Updated the URL!